# How to connect to an Azure MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, azure

I am trying to work with JPA and a MySQL database hosted on the Azure cloud. I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-data-jpa-with-azure-mysql).

But when it comes to running the application in order to test it: **Package and test the sample application**, starting the app as a SpringBootApp in eclipse or with their commands I have errors.

I have looked at many answers and here are some of the things that's I've tried:

1. I was at the beginning developing my own app so I have switched to their git example. Nothing changed
2. I have added some dependencies in my pom.xml (like mysqlconnector)
3. I have added the mysqlconnector.jar to my project's jars with the add external jar option

Here are:

**My pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-on-azure</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Spring Data JPA sample with Azure Database services</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>mysql</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>postgresql</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>sql</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

**My application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<server_name>.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/mysqldb?useSSL=true&requireSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=<admin_name>@<server_name>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
```

**My errors:**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.7.RELEASE)

2019-11-28 16:24:03.122  INFO 30624 --- [           main] c.m.azure.samples.spring.Application     : Starting Application on LFR036704 with PID 30624 (started by clomon in C:\Users\clomon\Documents\TAF\FormationAzure\Git clone azure tests\spring-data-jpa-on-azure)
2019-11-28 16:24:03.125  INFO 30624 --- [           main] c.m.azure.samples.spring.Application     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-11-28 16:24:03.168  INFO 30624 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5a3bc7ed: startup date [Thu Nov 28 16:24:03 CET 2019]; root of context hierarchy
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/clomon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.11.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2019-11-28 16:24:03.892  INFO 30624 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8febf7d9] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-11-28 16:24:04.175  INFO 30624 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-11-28 16:24:04.200  INFO 30624 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-11-28 16:24:04.200  INFO 30624 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.35
2019-11-28 16:24:04.205  INFO 30624 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\OpenJDK11\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/OpenJDK11/Bin/server;C:/Program Files/OpenJDK11/Bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\OpenJDK11\Bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\clomon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\clomon\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\clomon\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\clomon\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\;C:\Users\clomon\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Users\clomon\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Mono\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin;C:\Users\clomon\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\clomon\Documents\TAF\mySql\bin;;C:\Users\clomon\eclipse\java-2019-09\eclipse;;.]
2019-11-28 16:24:04.361  INFO 30624 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-11-28 16:24:04.361  INFO 30624 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1198 ms
2019-11-28 16:24:04.425  INFO 30624 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-11-28 16:24:04.428  INFO 30624 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-11-28 16:24:04.428  INFO 30624 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-11-28 16:24:04.428  INFO 30624 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-11-28 16:24:04.428  INFO 30624 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-11-28 16:24:04.536  INFO 30624 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-11-28 16:24:35.612 ERROR 30624 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:633) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1014) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2199) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2230) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2025) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:778) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:166) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:111) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aec2ba48.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$4(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aec2ba48$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6564d285.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365) ~[spring-context-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aec2ba48.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:819) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:725) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:819) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:725) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1087) ~[spring-context-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) ~[spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242) ~[spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230) ~[spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.microsoft.azure.samples.spring.Application.main(Application.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:101) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3011) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:568) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    ... 86 common frames omitted

2019-11-28 16:24:35.622  WARN 30624 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
[...]
```

It looks like the process is constantly trying to connect so I have escaped some of the error logs.

Comment: I have already took a look at these answers. But I am trying to work with JPA(/hibernate) on a MySQL database on Azure. I made JDBC works in local and on the azure and JPA also but only on my local MySQL server. I am following the microsoft tutorials and it's not working. I guess that I have a problem connecting to the Azure MySQL server.

Comment: If i'm reading correctly you're running the app locally? Any time I've had issues connecting to Azure databases from an app running locally it's been relating to firewall rules in Azure. You need to explicit allow comms to the DB server from your local machine as per these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-firewall-rules.